# kafka source connector doesn't populate topics

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create a kafka connector to read data from two tables (`TBLCFG01` and `TBLMSG01`) into two topics in kafka (`myapp.prefix.TBLCFG01` and `myapp.prefix.TBLMSG01`) - according to a [tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector) from Confluent .

We're using

- Lenses for Apache Kafka to administrate kafka - so I don't have access to a console.
- jdbc source connectors from Confluent.

I created the two topics and the connector. Here's the properties file of the connector in JSON notation:

```json
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:db2://our.machine.intra.net:12345/MYAPPTST",
  "mode": "bulk",
  "topic.prefix": "myapp.prefix.",
  "catalog.pattern": "myapp",
  "connection.user": "alice",
  "connection.password": "passw0rd",
  "table.whitelist": "TBLCNF01,TBLMSG01",
  "name": "myapp-source-jdbc-robs-test1"
}
```

Unfortunately, the connector is "running" but no tasks are started and the topics stay empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whilst the _connector_ is running, are the tasks within it? See https://youtu.be/1EenWEm-5dg?t=609 for how to check this

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to a console. But, in the lenses GUI I can see the connector is running but there are 0 tasks working for it.

Comment: When running properly a connector should have at least one task, and that task needs to be running. It might be that there are no tasks because no objects are matched. I think you're somehow going to need to get access to the Kafka Connect worker logs so that you can increase the debug level to check the objects being matched by the config.